# c# wpf openFileDialog не работает

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void selectFile_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog fd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    fd.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
    fd.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    bool? res = fd.ShowDialog();
    if (res == true)
    {
        selectedFilePath_textbox.Text = fd.FileName;
    }

    ///////

    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
    dlg.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
    dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dlgres = dlg.ShowDialog(); ;
    if (dlgres == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        selectedFilePath_textbox.Text = dlg.FileName;
    }
}
```

В обоих случаях форма теряет фокус и сразу же получает его и диалог не открывается. Есть решение?
В References подключил System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Проблема не в этом коде, у меня все прекрасно работает в обоих случаях. Может неверное имя кнопки или что-то еще.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте вообще с нуля сделал, так и логики можно дополнительной навесить и будет подлежать кастомизации. Но опять же, если имеет смысл в вашем случае.

Comment: С нуля это как?

Comment: Просто новое окно, у которого есть `TreeView` для получения списка папок, и `ListBox` для отображения и файлов, и папок.